# How to externally check Kubernetes readiness on deployment?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes, continuous-deployment, azure-aks

Our goal is to make sure the deployment was successful and the service is available
We already encountered a situation where the `Ingress` role was not correctly configured and the API's were down

We thought about deploying to a `staging` namespace, do a `readiness` call from outside the cluster and **if everything checks out**, move the deployment to its production namespace **if not**, delete the staging and declare the deployment as failed.

Is there a better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Are you using helm for deployment?

Comment: @BimalVasan Yes, I do, currently running `helm upgrade --install --wait ...`

Comment: i dont  think its a good idea. the healthchecks are meant to detect pod failures, not ingress misconfigurations.

Comment: @efratlevitan I didn't attend to use health-check; I can use a dedicated API or an existing one, the issue is the approach.

Comment: We have two levels of checking. First through readiness probe in the helm chart and deployment files if the pod/app is not up. Then we do a smoke test using external url.

Comment: @bismalvasan what do you do if the smoke test fails? Can you rollback?

Answer (score 0):

Using kubernetes [namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) for staging and production is a nice idea.

Another way is to:

1. Create a staging kubernetes cluster and install the deployment, service and ingress in it.
2. Test readiness of deployment, service and ingress in the staging cluster from outside the staging cluster.
3. Move deployment to production cluster if everything is working fine as expected.
4. Use `kubectl`'s `config` and `context` to [switch between staging cluster and production cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#define-clusters-users-and-contexts):

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Config
   preferences: {}
   clusters:
   - cluster:
     name: staging
   - cluster:
     name: production
   ...
   ```

Comment: Thank you, that looks like a nice approach, however, since we have multiple clusters (different regions) it's not so practical for us to have two times more clusters than really needed

Comment: You can re-use a single staging cluster (with multiple staging namespaces in it) to test deployments of multiple production clusters, and use `kubectl` and `helm` to jump between clusters/configs/contexts/namespaces - don't know if this works for you.

Comment: I wish it was that easy, I don't think I can toggle configs for clusters in different regions. Azure BTW